# Swift 2.0: Protocol Extension Class Method returning Self

Tags: swift, swift2, protocol-extension

In order to extend some functionalities of my `NSManagedObject` subclasses, I have defined a series of protocols:

```
protocol ManagedObjectFindable {
    static func find(format:String, arguments: [AnyObject]?, inContext context:NSManagedObjectContext, entityName:String?) -> Self?
}

protocol UniquelyIdentifiable: ManagedObjectFindable {

    var identifier: NSNumber? { get }
    static func findWithIdentifier(identifier: Int, inContext context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self?
}
```

So then every `NSManagedObject` that has identifier in its data model entity can conform to `UniquelyIdentifiable`.

For that purpose I am utilising Swift 2.0 Protocol Extensions, where:

```
extension UniquelyIdentifiable {

    static func findWithIdentifier(identifier: Int, inContext context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        return self.find("identifier == %lld", arguments: [NSNumber(longLong: Int64(identifier))], inContext: context, entityName:nil)
    }
}
```

Where find is defined as:

```
extension NSManagedObject: ManagedObjectFindable {
    /** returns single entity if found, nil otherwise */
    class func find(format:String, arguments: [AnyObject]?, inContext context:NSManagedObjectContext, entityName:String? = nil) -> Self? {

        let objectEntityName:String
        if let name = entityName {
            objectEntityName = name
        } else {
            objectEntityName = String(self)
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(objectEntityName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, argumentArray: arguments)

        var persistentEntityº:NSManagedObject?
        context.performBlockAndWait {

            do {
                let fetchResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                if (fetchResults.count != 0){
                    persistentEntityº = fetchResults.first as? NSManagedObject
                }
            } catch {}
        }

        if let persistentEntity = persistentEntityº {
            return _safeObjectSelfCast(persistentEntity)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
func _unsafeObjectSelfCast<T>(obj: AnyObject!) -> T { return obj as! T }
func _safeObjectSelfCast<T>(obj: AnyObject) -> T?   { return obj as? T }
```

Now these methods correctly return Self? and compiler is silent on the coding time, however when compiling it gives me that error `Method 'findWithIdentifier(_:inContext:)' in non-final class must return 'Self' to conform to protocol 'UniquelyIdentifiable'`

Now the thing is that if instead of implementing that method in a protocol extension I would just extend my `NSManagedObject` subclass, it will go fine, but that kills the purpose of protocol extensions, when you are completely duplicating the same code across dozens of your `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Any workaround, or I am really missing something?

Comment: Your code compiles without errors in my Xcode 7.1.1

Comment: @MartinR: try adding to NSMOSubclass: 

extension SomeManagedObjectSubclass: UniquelyIdentifiable {}

In that case it won't...

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer:* 
Change `Self?` in extension to the `NSManagedObject?`.

*Long answer:* `Self` in protocol requirement acts as a placeholder for the class that will implement that protocol. So if you have

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
   func returnSomething() -> Self
}
```

That means that if you implement it on `Int`, function `returnSomething()` should return `Int`, and if you implement it on `Double` it should return `Double`.

Since you are implementing `UniquelyIdentifiable` on `NSManagedObject` and your protocol has `Self?` requirement, you should return `NSManagedObject?`.

Comment: In my case it should return the instance of Optional(NSManagedObject Subclass), not Optional(NSManagedObject), yes it will work but you want to return Optional(NSManagedObjectSubclass)

the reason to return Self? instead of NSManagedObject? is because you can have many different NSManagedObject subclasses,

and if the subclass conforms to this protocol, it will already implement findWithIdentifier, which is in protocol extension default implementation.